# MinSdkversion doesn't change in gradle build script

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I changed my minsdkversion to '23' in my Androidmanifest.XML. Yet when I run the app on my phone(api 22) it gets executed. I found it was always overridden by the value specified in gradle build script . should I always change the minsdkversion in gradle build script?